# Необходимо составить SQL запрос с использованием оператора CASE и сравнить разницу в днях

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

Есть таблица:

| IDname | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 31.08.2023 | 09.10.2023 |
| 1122 | 08.08.2023 | 08.08.2023 |

Необходимо вывести значение 1 если:

1- даты равны

2- разница между датами 1 и 2 составляет 31 день.

Вот что сейчас получилось, выполняется только первое условие.

```
select 
  case 
    when Date1 =Date2 then '1' else '0' end as ap31,
   t.IDname, t.Date1 , t.Date2 
from table_name t
```

Помогите со второй частью.
Забыл добавить, что это все в PLSQL Oracle.

Comment: ```CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date1, date2) IN (-31, 0, 31)```

Comment: @Akina - что такое DATEDIFF?  нет в оракле такого

Comment: @ESkri Когда писался комментарий, тега конкретной СУБД у вопроса не было. А потому была использована функция, имя которой говорит само за себя. Конкретно в Оракле - даты просто тупо вычитаются.

Answer (score 0):

Могут быть разные варианты, в том числе с использованием функции `ABS`, см. [онлайн демо на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6b392/4)

```sql
SELECT CASE
    WHEN t.date1 = t.date2 THEN 1
    WHEN ABS(t.date1 - t.date2) = 31 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS ap31, t.*
FROM tbl t;

SELECT CASE ABS(t.date1 - t.date2)
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
    WHEN 31 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS ap31, t.*
FROM tbl t;

-- Akina solution
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (t.date1 - t.date2) IN (-31, 0, 31) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS ap31, t.*
FROM tbl t;
```